# Flot chart stackpercent tooltip with line chart %p not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip, flot, stacked-area-chart

So I'm using flot charts and the stackpercent plugin which says to provide support for the flot tooltip plugin. Now I am using the plugin with a line chart instead of a bar chart. This seems to still work with the plugin, but for some reason the flot tooltip doesn't display the %p properly. It just shows the text '%p' rather than the percentage. Any ideas?

Update:
I thought it might have to do with the fact that I was using a line chart and not a bar chart like the examples for the plugin, but they aren't appearing for the bar chart either...

Comment: Please can you provide your code in question, or even better a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so can see issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current tooltip plugin only supports percent with pie charts.  The `jquery.flot.stackpercent.js` plugin stores the percents internally a little different since it needs to work with multiple series.

Fear not, though, I forked the tooltip plugin and added support [here](https://github.com/larsenmtl/flot.tooltip).

Here's a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rpXb/).

Comment: Thans for responding. I have tried installing the latest foot tooltip but for some reason it isn't working. I have seen it used in the way you have shown...

Comment: @user3129120, by "latest", do you mean the one I fixed to work with the stackpercent plugin?  https://github.com/larsenmtl/flot.tooltip/blob/master/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.js

Comment: yeah. I did a bower install for the latest. That should work right? The code seems to be the same...

Comment: Did you install from my fork?

Comment: Thanks for being so responsive! I think i did. Could you tell me exactly how to do that? My last resort will be trying to copy the file directly (although I might have done that before)

Comment: @user3129120, I'm not familiar with bower.  I just tried installing it and npm won't play nice with my company's proxy server.  I'm probably missing something here, but I can't see how bower is easier then just downloading a file...

Comment: thanks for the help! yeah i tried just copying the file you linked and that worked. Thanks so much!